# 2 dots and three dots in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

what does the 2 dots mean in dart like this one when you want to create a Paint:

```
var paint = Paint()
..shader = gradient.createShader(rect)
```

and the 3 dots like this sample I saw it in flutter sample

```
ListView(
        children: [
          ListTile(title: Text('Basics', style: headerStyle)),
          ...basicDemos.map((d) => DemoTile(d)),
          ListTile(title: Text('Misc', style: headerStyle)),
          ...miscDemos.map((d) => DemoTile(d)),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two dots (`..`) is the syntax for [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation):

```dart
var button = querySelector('#confirm');
button.text = 'Confirm';
button.classes.add('important');
button.onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```

can be rewritten to:

```dart
querySelector('#confirm')
  ..text = 'Confirm'
  ..classes.add('important')
  ..onClick.listen((e) => window.alert('Confirmed!'));
```

---

Three dots (`...`) is the [spread operator](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator):

```dart
var list = [1, 2, 3];
var list2 = [0, ...list];
```

`list2` contains `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.